# Copy and rearrange specific data that contains cells with letters and numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet with data arranged randomly with numbers and letters throughout Columns B and C. I also have an input cell located in cell "O7" and an output cell located in "P7" where a user can input any value (1,1a, 2,2b, etc...) and the code will use these values to find and copy the value in A

My code (below) runs through and finds the value in B based on the value in "O7" and copies the corresponding value in column A (2 times) for that row to "Sheet4." It then looks to the next cell in column C and uses that value to find the next row in Column B with that value. Then it copies that row's value in Column A to Sheet 4 under the previous one.

My problem is that my code can't distinguish between "1" and a value with a letter like "1a" for either the input or output value. It just sees that there is a "1" and copies the value in A. I believe I may not be setting my NewStart variable as the next value to look up correctly or my function may be missing something to distinguish between "1" and "1a"?

```
Sub NewerFind()

Dim Startval As Long
Dim Endval As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Rng As range
Dim Output As Long
Dim NewStart As Long

Dim Val As Long
Dim Valnew As Long

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet3").range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Startval = GetSingleFromString(Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(7, "O").Value)

Output = 2

NewStart = Startval


For X = 7 To LastRow

    Val = GetSingleFromString(Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(X, 2).Value)       'if i set the variables equal to a string, do i need the GetSingleFromString function?
    Valnew = GetSingleFromString(Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(X, 3).Value)
    Endval = GetSingleFromString(Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(7, "P").Value)

    If Val = Endval Then
    Exit Sub

    ElseIf Val = NewStart Then
            Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(Output, 1).Value = _
                 Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(X, 1).Value
            Output = Output + 1

            Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(Output, 1).Value = _
                 Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(X, 1).Value
            Output = Output + 1
            NewStart = Valnew
    End If
    'need line of code to set NewStart as the value of the cell to the right...???????

Next X
End Sub
```

This is the function I'm using to enable the code to include cells with letters. Without it, it skips cells with letters:

```
Private Function GetSingleFromString(ByVal InString As String) As Single

    If Len(InString) <= -1 Then
        GetSingleFromString = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim X As Long
    Dim Temp1 As String
    Dim Output As String

    For X = 1 To Len(InString)
        Temp1 = Mid(InString, X, 1)
        If IsNumeric(Temp1) Or Temp1 = "." Then Output = Output & Temp1
    Next

    If Len(Output) > 0 Then
        GetSingleFromString = CSng(Output)
    Else
        GetSingleFromString = -1
    End If

End Function
```

This is my excel Sheet:

```
A   B    C    D       E                                   
1   1   1a  78.15   77.68     (Row 7)      
2   1a  2   77.18   76.92
3   2   3   76.92   76.63
4   3   4   76.13   75.78
5   4   4a  75.78   75.21
6   4a  5   75.11   74.87
7   5   5a  74.87   74.69
8   5a  6   73.94   73.6
9   6   6a  73.1    72.71
10  6a  6b  72.41   72.18
11  6b  10  72.18   71.6
12  10  11  71.3    70.89
13  11  12  70.89   69.83
14  12  13  69.83   68.68
15  13  14  68.68   67.68
16  14  15  67.63   66.46
17  15  16  66.01   64.84
18  16  16a 64.24   63.72
19  16a 16b 56.82   56.37
20  16b 16c 56.37   55.18
21  16c OUT 47.28   47.27
22  7   7a  83.12   76.07
23  7a  8   76.17   75.99
24  8   9   74.79   74.41
25  9   6   74.51   74           (Row 31)
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do; all I can see is that you want to find cells with a matching value, which may be the entire value, or just the numeric part of a value.

What I do know is that Range.Find isn't as useful as you think: it sometimes makes a string comparison if either the search value or the seek range is a string, and sometimes decides it's 'no match' if tries the numeric value 1 against the string "1", depending on the formatting in the cells.

It'll definitely treat "1" versus "1a" as 'no match', if you've set `LookAt:=xlWhole`, because you've specified that the whole of the value, each and every character, must match the search string exactly.

That's fine, most of the time, if you wanted to treat "1" versus "1a" as 'no match', and only match "1"to "1" and "1a to "1a".

If you wanted to treat  "1" versus "1a" as a 'find', you have two choices:

1. Use the partial match option in Range.Find by setting
   `LookAt:=xlPart`, and hope that it doesn't get confused by formatting. And most of the time, it doesn't get confused; so you're probably fine.
2. Search through the cells in each range with VBA, using 'Like', which allows you to specify partial matches, single digits, and match-from-the-list for specific characters like [1234567890]

Just to get you started with 'Like':

`"1" = "1a"`     returns False 
 `"1" LIKE "1a"`  returns False 
 `"1" LIKE "1*"`  returns True, although this isn't a very useful thing to know 
 `"1a" LIKE "#*"` returns True, and this looks a bit more relevant because you've identified a value that starts with a number, and you can test that at the top of an If... Then block containing further logic to make the match you actually want.

Full documentation for the 'Like' operator is here on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251796.aspx

Developers using other languages will use Regular Expressions for this kind of thing: but you'd need to import an external Regex library for that, as it isn't native to Excel and VBA.

Also: a string can never have a LEN of less than zero. Your test  `If Len(InString) <= -1 Then` needed to be for zero, or less than 1.

Comment: I took out that beginning part because I didn't need it for this. IBasically, I have a cell designated as an input value (O7) and another as an output value(P7). anyone can edit this cell with any number they see in columns B and C. I want to search column B for the input value, copy the adjacent value in A to another worksheet, then use the value adjacent to B in column C, and use that as my new value to look for in column B, until column C's value equals the output.